# Javascript: assign object to variable

Tags: javascript, object, variables, ecmascript-2016

I have an existing object with some properties:

```
var props = {
  filters: {
    brightness: 0,
    opacity: 1,
  }
}
```

So, I want to assign `filter` properties of this object to another object during variable declaration:

```
var sprite = {
  configs: {
    image: 'pic.png',
    // <- assign `props.filters` right here
  }
}
```

As there result I want to get such object:

```
{
  configs: {
    image: 'pic.png',
    brightness: 0,
    opacity: 1,
  }
}
```

I can do it just after `sprite` variable declaration like this:

```
Object.assign(sprite.configs, props.filters);
```

But is it possible to assign properties of another object during variable declaration?

It would be very convenient in case there are many-many props in one object and JS will allow to implement such assignment during variable declaration to eliminate redundant post processing.

Comment: `configs: { image: 'pic.png', ...props.filters }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to "spread" the values of props inside the sprite variable.

```js
const props = {
  filters: {
    brightness: 0,
    opacity: 1,
  }
};

const sprite = {
  configs: {
    image: 'pic.png',
    ...props.filters,
  }
};

console.log(sprite);
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've just tried same thing but in wrong way with `{...}` curly braces! Don't know why...